# A double value randomly genetrated is getting changed while assigning to another double variable

Tags: java, double, variable-assignment

In this code I am generating a random double value using `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble()` and storing it into a double array `R1[]`. Next I checked the value of each R1 element with pc which is another double variable containing `pc=x/100` but it reflected a wired behaviour. Then I try to assign R1 elements to k1 and printed both R1 and k1. Surprisingly it printed absolutely different value.

```
public void select_parent(double x) {

    int k=0;
    int i=0;
    double pc=x/100;
    System.out.println("cross over rate="+pc);
    double []R1=new double[population];

    while(k<population) {

        R1[k]=ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0.0,1.0);
        System.out.println("R["+k+"]="+R1[k]);
        double k1=R1[k];

        System.out.println("outside if k1="+k1);
        if(R1[k]<pc) {
            parentchromosome.put(i++, k);
            System.out.println("Inside if k1="+k1);
        }

        k++;
    }
    System.out.println("parentchromose="+parentchromosome);
}
```

Comment: You're printing ```R[k]``` and then ```k1 = R1[k]```, they are different arrays.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Jorn. Now I am having a problem with StringBuffer. append() method giving the desired result. I hope I will post it here